# Writing through Telnet with Python

Tags: python, telnet, python-3.4

I'm still somewhat new to python and fiddling with telnet in general, but I've got an issue here. For some reason this code I have written doesn't stop to let me actually write anything through the telnet terminal, it just runs to completion without stopping. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help out?

```
import telnetlib
import time
HOST = input("IP Address: ")
command = b" "

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port = 23, timeout = 20)
time.sleep(10)
tn.write(command + b"\n")
ret1 = tn.read_eager()
time.sleep(10)
print(ret1)
tn.write(b"001 rq version\n")
ret2 = tn.read_until(b"_DNE", timeout = 5)
time.sleep(10)
print(ret2)
tn.write(command + b"\n")

print("Success!")
tn.close()
```

EDIT: Sorry, I should've specified more clearly.

Basically, after it gets the IP, it connects to the host machine just fine. The problem after that is the line "tn.write(command + b"\n")", according to everything I've looked up this should allow the user to input whatever they want to type in, but the program does not stop to allow the user to type anything at all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the telnetlib, so this may be wrong, but does the program need to prompt for input besides the IP?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it just runs to completion without stopping". Can you please clarify!

Comment: After you get the IP input by the user, you never again ask for any input from the user. Is it asking you to input the IP? What exacty is the output?

Comment: You need to use read_until or a related function otherwise it will attempt to read everything from the farside until the connection closes. See the example in the documentation of telnetlib: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/telnetlib.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like `command` is basically an empty string, and that doesn't seem to change at any point(except for the '\n'). Each time you do `tn.write(command + b"\n")`, you are just sending `b"\n"` down the wire. You're not prompting the user to type anything. Try something like:

```
command = input("Enter command: ")
tn.write(b"{}\n".format(command))
```

In place of just writing:

```
tn.write(command + b"\n")
```